# how to split NSString if the string is containing special character such as . or /

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsregularexpression

Im working on an email project and there is an issue to get the name of the folder. Such as some of the providers (Gmail) returns the folder's as `[Gmail]/Inbox`. However, other returns `Something.Inbox`.

What I am doing right now is ( it works only if the path is `[Gmail]/Inbox` )

```
+ (NSString *)formatDisplayFolderPath:(NSString *)path {
    NSInteger index = [path rangeOfString:@"/"].location;

    if (index != NSNotFound && index + 1 < path.length) {
        return [path substringFromIndex:index + 1];
    }
    return path;
}
```

So in order to split string such as Something.Inbox, i should have another method to take care of it and I dont think it is a good way to do it because it does not cover other special characters.

I am looking for a way so that if any providers pass me anything like `Something.Inbox` or `Something*Inbox` or `Something|Inbox`, it can detect a separator and split the string automatically.I am searching about the NSRegularExpression but dont know how to use it.

Any thoughts about this and how to deal with it. Thanks

Comment: Consider `[NSString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:]`.

Comment: `NSInteger indexSlash = [path rangeOfString:@"/"].location; NSInteger indexDot = [path rangeOfString:@"."].location;`, etc.

Comment: thanks all, it read over `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` but did not realize it does help until now